# What is the white area around the UILabel when it is selected in storyboard?

Tags: autolayout, uikit, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

What is the white area around the UILabel when it is selected in storyboard[image: shortcut of the scene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the `Xcode` UI behaviour of Xcode's interface builder, which highlights the selected UI component. It's not just for `UILabel`, every UI component has this effect.

[image: Xcode Interface builder]